# PHP vprintf in magic method

Tags: php, magic-methods

My PHP contains translatable values as constants. By calling the class with the name of the constant, the formatted value should be returned.

```
class Test {
    const translation_value = 'Foo %s, bar %s';
    public static function __callStatic($string, $args) {
        return vsprintf(constant("self::" . $string), $args);
    }
}
```

If I call the class via `Test::{"translation_value"}(["test", "test2"]);` PHP show two errors:

> Notice: Array to string conversion [...] on line 4
>   PHP Warning:  vsprintf(): Too few arguments [...] on line 4

What am I doing wrong?

If I test the vprintf function by calling it manually (`vsprintf("Foo %s, bar %s", ["val1", "val2"]);`) PHP creates the expected output: **Foo val1, bar val2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `__callStatic($string, $args)` is a list of arguments. You have 1 argument, so you need either to use first element of the array:

```
return vsprintf(constant("self::" . $string), $args[0]);
```

Or invoke it with flat parameters:

```
Test::translation_value("test", "test2");
```